# Finding minimum in a descending rotated sorted array with duplicates

Tags: arrays, binary-search

For this question ([154. Find Minimum in Rotated Sorted Array II](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-minimum-in-rotated-sorted-array-ii)
), I have a solution:

```
   def findMin(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(nums)
        left, right = 0, n - 1

        while left < right:

            mid = left + (right - left) // 2 

   
            if nums[mid] == nums[right]:
                right -= 1  

            elif nums[mid] > nums[right]:
                left = mid + 1

            else:
                right = mid 

        return nums[left]
```

My intuition for why we compare with the right is, that this is an ascending array. So when we compare mid and right, 2 things can happen:

1. mid > right => influx point to right (nums go up and then again come down and go up)
2. An influx point could be to the left of mid

Now the same logic will not work when comparing with left *because* this is a rotated **ascending** array:

1. If left > mid then there is an influx point to the left of the array
2. But if left < mid then this does not give us a lot of useful info to reduce our search space. Eiter left is the minimum in an ascending array not rotated OR influx point is to the right.

Based on the intuition, I came up with this to find the minimum in a rotated array that is sorted in descending order, where I compare with the left pointer.

```
   def findMin(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(nums)
        left, right = 0, n - 1

        while left < right:

            mid = left + (right - left) // 2 

            # Fails due to this logic of ignoring duplicates 
            if nums[left] == nums[mid]:
                left += 1
            elif nums[left] < nums[mid]:
                right = mid - 1
            else:
                left = mid

            

        return nums[left]
```

But it fails on inputs like `[1, 3]`. As mid and left are both 0, it goes in the path to ignore duplicates and incorrectly does `left += 1`. If I did not have that check to skip duplicates, then we would get infinite looping with no updates to the range.

So another reason why comparing with right works but not left is: For the base case of 2 element array when we compare right, mid = 0 and right = 1. But when we compare with left, both left and mid are 0.

I have been thinking for 4 hours on this but still kinda stuck. My question is:

1. Is my intuition about why we compare with right correct? (that it works because this is an ascending array that is rotated)
2. How do we make this work when comparing with left? Both for ascending and descending rotated arrays?